# Using Lambda function in sorted

Tags: python

regular unsorted dictionary

```
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}
```

dictionary sorted by key

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

dictionary sorted by value

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
```

How lambda function is working in the above lines. what is t[0], t[1]?

Comment: You need to format your question and be more precise, it would be good if you could start by posting your code in the right format, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Working of lambda function in here is like, Sort the list of tuple with the second item.
    sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])

`d.items()` will be like this.

```
[('orange', 2), ('pear', 1), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)]
```

So `lambda t:t[1]` it return a second elemnt in a given iterator. So it will sort based on the second element. Same as for the `lambda t:t[0]` it's sort with first element.

Example to understand the lambda function.

```
In [39]: func = lambda t:t[1]

In [40]: [func(i) for i in d.items()]
Out[40]: [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` is anonymous function. It is convenient to use when specifying sort order, but there is nothing magic about `lambda`, if you wanted too, you could define the function explicitly:

```
def sorter(x):                                                                                               
    return x[1]                                                                                              

print sorted(d.items(), key=sorter)
```

`t` is the an element in `d.items()`, so when you choose `t[0]` you are sorting by first element and when you choose `t[1]` you are sorting by second element. If you were to choose `t[2]` you would get `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

First some background: The `item()` function returns a list of tuples in the dictionary.

This line:

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

In this line, the sorted function iterates through each item (a tuple), and as per the passed lambda uses the first element of the tuple (the key) to sort (`t[0]`). The second example follows the same idea, except with the second element of the tuple (the value). As such, each line respectively results in sorting by key and value.